# AngularJS - upload and display image using FileReader API (multiple files)

Tags: angularjs, file, upload, filereader

I use the following example, it works perfectly , but I'd like to upload multiple images simultaneously.

http://jsfiddle.net/kkhxsgLu/2/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="step in stepsModel">
    <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{step}}" />
</div>

<input type='file' ng-model-instant onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(this)" />
```

```
 $scope.stepsModel = [];

$scope.imageUpload = function(element){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
    reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
}

$scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.stepsModel.push(e.target.result);
    });
}
```

Thank you kindly help me, I started with angularjs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

http://jsfiddle.net/orion514/kkhxsgLu/136/

:)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="step in stepsModel">
    <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{step}}" />
</div>

<input type='file' ng-model-instant 
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(event)"
       multiple />
```

```
$scope.stepsModel = [];

$scope.imageUpload = function(event){
     var files = event.target.files; //FileList object

     for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         var file = files[i];
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded; 
             reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
}

$scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.stepsModel.push(e.target.result);
    });
}
```

Comment: How would you do this for a situation where you want to upload 1 image at a time and have a submit button? Could you please post the code for that?

Comment: @gerogeawg Awesome answer

Answer (score 1):

### Directive to get files input with `ng-model` (multiple files)

The AngularJS built-in `<input>` directive does not handle `<input type=file>`. One needs a custom directive for that.

```
<input type="file" files-input ng-model="fileArray" multiple>
```

The `files-input` directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

The above directive adds a change listener that updates the model with the files property of the `input` element.

This directive enables `<input type=file>` to automatically work with the `ng-change` and `ng-form` directives.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/xAP35pC7iA5hm6Sip5Ms?p=preview)

---

### Inline Demo of `files-input` Directive

```js
angular.module("app",[]);

angular.module("app").directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>AngularJS Input `type=file` Demo</h1>
    
    <input type="file" files-input ng-model="fileArray" multiple>
    
    <h2>Files</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="file in fileArray">
      {{file.name}}
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Zypps987, try using var file = files[0], not inside a loop.

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if you wrote out the code.